# How do I enable the Ubuntu One tray applet?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, ubuntu-one, applet

I am running 10.04 and I am unable to get a tray applet to appear for Ubuntu One. I am sure there was an applet in 9.04 (Jaunty) and 9.10 (Karmic).

I have the package ubuntuone-client-gnome installed which Synaptic tells me

> "This package contains the tray applet and Nautilus extension, providing integration with the GNOME desktop."

The applet is not on the "Add to panel..." list and there doesn't appear to be anything in the menus.

So how do I make the applet appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the Ubuntu One applet has been integrated into the 'me menu'. At the bottom of the me menu you should see something like:

```
Chat Accounts...
Broadcast Accounts...
Ubuntu One...
```

Click on 'Ubuntu One...' to edit Ubuntu One preferences. Other actions are done in nautilus. You can right click on a file/folder (in your home folder) and click 'Synchronise on Ubuntu One' for example.

Comment: Aha, thanks. It is there, but just brings up the preferences window, it isn't the status icon that pops up notifications like "Synchronisation complete". Is that applet gone now? You could click on it and open the folder or web interface etc.

Comment: Whilst this is not the answer I wanted, it appears this is the correct answer and the useful applet that once was has been replaced by something not so useful. Back to tailing log files to get the status then !

Comment: I use the u1sdtool when I want to know what the daemon is doing.

Answer (score 6):

Those of you wanting to know more about what the syncdaemon is doing may be interested in `magicicada`. It's a desktop app that talks to syncdaemon over dbus. It's already in Maverick, and you can get it off the PPA for Lucid: `ppa:chicharreros/ppa`.

"A tool for engineers by engineers" would aptly describe it.

Answer (score 5):

Richard - At Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, we removed the applet that was there in Ubuntu 9.10. Hopefully, there will be some updates to the network indicatory menu in Ubuntu 11.04 that we will be able to take advantage of to show Ubuntu One sync status. Until then, you can use Jorge's technique of running u1sdtool from the Terminal.

`u1sdtool --help` returns a list of the arguments you can use to tell what's happening with sync. Some ones that I use frequently are

- `u1sdtool -c`
- `u1sdtool -s`
- `u1sdtool --waiting-content`
- `u1sdtool --current-transfers`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are still interested in it have a look at: [ubuntuone-indicator](http://blog.rtg.in.ua/2010/10/have-you-seen-my-weather-applet.html)

Comment: Taras: Thanks for posting this answer and congratulations on starting a great project. Looking at the amount and type of comments posted there suggests I was not alone in my frustration of this lack of functionality. Have a +1.